# Access: Order entries in a Group By column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a query in Microsoft Access 2010, that takes all the entries in Column A, and gives a count of each within the last 7 days.

When running the query, with a `GROUP BY` clause, I get the entries of `Column A` in alphabetical order as required, except one of the entries called `Other`, which I'd like to always appear at the bottom.

How could I do this, preferably without changing the values of `Column A`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a two-key `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY IIF(col1 = "Other", 1, 0),
         col1 ASC
```

The first handles the `"Other"` column.  The second does the ordering for the rest of the names (including `NULL`, were it one of the values).

Answer (score -1):

Will something similar do the trick?

```
CREATE TABLE Col_DATE (col1 VARCHAR(5), col2 DATE) 

INSERT INTO Col_DATE VALUES ('aa','17/02/2016')
INSERT INTO Col_DATE VALUES ('az','18/02/2016')
INSERT INTO Col_DATE VALUES ('ab','20/02/2016')
INSERT INTO Col_DATE VALUES ('aa','17/02/2016')
INSERT INTO Col_DATE VALUES ('az','18/02/2016')
INSERT INTO Col_DATE VALUES ('ab','20/02/2016')
INSERT INTO Col_DATE VALUES ('Other','20/02/2016')

SELECT col1,COUNT(col1) FROM Col_DATE WHERE col2  >= NOW()-7
ORDER BY IIf([col1] = 'Other',col1) ASC
```